# Splitting df by factors, applying a function, and returning combined df in r

Tags: r

I realise there are a number of questions on this topic, but I haven’t been able to solve my problem by looking through the various answers. I have a df - an extract of which is appended below:

```
ID = as.factor(c("1","1","1","1","1",
                 "2","2","2",
                 "3","3","3","3",
                 "4","4","4","4","4"))
AdDate = c("2010-03-04", "2010-04-05", "2011-01-23", "2011-03-20", "2012-07-08",
           "2010-12-02", "2011-05-17", "2011-09-11",
           "2010-04-11", "2010-05-15", "2011-02-22", "2011-09-23",
           "2009-10-04", "2010-02-15", "2010-08-17", "2011-06-20", "2012-04-08")
OpofInterest = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
df = data.frame(ID, AdDate, OpofInterest)
```

What I then want to do is split the df by ID into a number of dataframes (4 in this example), and then apply the function below to assign whether the other episodes (each row) are before (pre-surgery), the same (per-surgery), or after the operation of interest (post-surgery) for each individual (ID) based on AdDate. I am new to R and programming and have produced a function below. In reality, I have thousands of IDs and episodes, and around 80 columns, so I can’t individually subset and apply a function which I got to work after some adjustment.

```
prepostassignment <- function (df) {

df_OpofInterest = subset(df,(df["OpofInterest"] == "TRUE"))  

for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {

if (df$AdDate[i] < df_OpofInterest$AdDate) {
    df$Pre_Post_Assignment[i] = "Pre"

} else if (df$AdDate[i] == df_OpofInterest$AdDate) {
  df$Pre_Post_Assignment[i] = "Per"

} else if (df$AdDate[i] > df_OpofInterest$AdDate) { 
  df$Pre_Post_Assignment[i] = "Post"

  }
 }
}
```

I have played around with by, tapply, aggregate, ddply and can’t seem to come up with a 
solution. I have also been getting the following error message when using the function on a manual subset:

missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

I have read up on this as well but can’t understand where it is going wrong in my particular code

What I want to end up with is the following:

```
ID = as.factor(c("1","1","1","1","1",
                 "2","2","2",
                 "3","3","3","3",
                 "4","4","4","4","4"))
AdDate = c("2010-03-04", "2010-04-05", "2011-01-23", "2011-03-20", "2012-07-08",
           "2010-12-02", "2011-05-17", "2011-09-11",
           "2010-04-11", "2010-05-15", "2011-02-22", "2011-09-23",
           "2009-10-04", "2010-02-15", "2010-08-17", "2011-06-20", "2012-04-08")
OpofInterest = c("FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE",
                 "FALSE", "FALSE", "TRUE", "FALSE", "FALSE")
Pre_Post_Assignment = c("Pre", "Pre", "Per", "Post", "Post",
                        "Pre", "Per", "Post",
                        "Pre", "Pre", "Per", "Post",
                        "Pre", "Pre", "Per", "Post", "Post")
df_new = data.frame(ID, AdDate, OpofInterest, Pre_Post_Assignment)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What are `df_OpofInterest` and `df_TAVI` in your second code chunk?

Comment: Apologies, df_TAVI was supposed to be df_OpofInterest. I was subsetting the 'Op of interest' to obtain the AdDate for use in the function

Comment: Why do you start with columns of class `character` (which then get converted to `factor`)? Shouldn't ID be `integer`, date be `Date`, OpofInterest be `logical`?

Comment: I assumed I may need the factor to split the df at some point. But yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is classic split-apply-combine analysis. Here is an option using `data.table`:

```
df = data.frame(ID, AdDate, OpofInterest, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
df$OpofInterest <- as.logical(df$OpofInterest)
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)
dt[, 
  cbind(
    .SD,
    Pre_Post_Assignment=
      ifelse(
         AdDate < AdDate[OpofInterest], 
         "Pre",
         ifelse(AdDate == AdDate[OpofInterest], "Per", "Post"
    ) ) ), 
  by=ID]
#     ID     AdDate OpofInterest Pre_Post_Assignment
#  1:  1 2010-03-04        FALSE                 Pre
#  2:  1 2010-04-05        FALSE                 Pre
#  3:  1 2011-01-23         TRUE                 Per
#  4:  1 2011-03-20        FALSE                Post
#  5:  1 2012-07-08        FALSE                Post
#  6:  2 2010-12-02        FALSE                 Pre
#  7:  2 2011-05-17         TRUE                 Per
#  8:  2 2011-09-11        FALSE                Post
#  9:  3 2010-04-11        FALSE                 Pre
# 10:  3 2010-05-15        FALSE                 Pre
# 11:  3 2011-02-22         TRUE                 Per
# 12:  3 2011-09-23        FALSE                Post
# 13:  4 2009-10-04        FALSE                 Pre
# 14:  4 2010-02-15        FALSE                 Pre
# 15:  4 2010-08-17         TRUE                 Per
# 16:  4 2011-06-20        FALSE                Post
# 17:  4 2012-04-08        FALSE                Post
```

You can also use `ddply` for this.  The meat of the actual calculation is the two nested `ifelse` statements.  The second argument to `[.data.table` is a list of the columns we want in the output in addition to the split/grouping columnn (`ID` here).  The `.SD` variable is a special `data.table` variable that contains all the columns in the group that are not referenced in the `by` argument (here it would contain `AdDate` and `OpofInterest`).  We `cbind` our additional vector to `.SD` to create our new result with the extra column.

A couple of other noteworthy points:

1. I converted dates to strings for the comparisons to work
2. I converted `OpofInterest` to logical

Finally, disclaimer, while the type of analysis performed here is split-apply-combine, the behind the scenes implementation in `data.table` does not split, and apply, rather, it subsets and iterates (I'm noting this here so Arun doesn't get mad at me).

---

EDIT: here is @BlueMagister's suggestion:

```
dt[, 
  Pre_Post_Assignment:=
    ifelse(
      AdDate < AdDate[OpofInterest], 
      "Pre",
      ifelse(AdDate == AdDate[OpofInterest], "Per", "Post")
    ),
   by=ID
]
```

which I think is cleaner and most likely faster as well.

Comment: thanks for the help and advice, I appreciate that. What would you suggest doing when you have 80+ columns for example, in the 'list(cols... = ifelse' section of your code? A named vector of column names?

Comment: @sgurwin, I modified answer to address your concern.  See the `.SD` stuff.

Comment: It would be better to define a new column than to `cbind` on `.SD`, no?

Comment: @BlueMagister, you mean with `:=`?  Then yes, probably.  Hadn't thought of that.